# Erro: unrecognized module type android_app_import. when building AOSP 10 r20+

Tags: android, android-source, archlinux, android-soong

Just started to build AOSP, for my Redmi Note 6 Pro
Got error "android_app_import" unrecognized module type

My PC (Arch Linux)
uname --all

```
Linux DEdSeC-PC 5.4.6-arch3-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 24 Dec 2019 04:36:53 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Sources

Device tree: https://github.com/being-yash-t/android_device_xiaomi_tulip

Common tree: https://github.com/AkhilmsAchu/android_device_xiaomi_sdm660-common

vendor tree: https://github.com/AkhilmsAchu/proprietary_vendor_xiaomi

Kernel Source: https://github.com/OktapraAmtono/mystic-kernel-sdm660

Error:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
TARGET_PRODUCT=arch_tulip
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=kryo
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=kryo
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.6-arch3-1-x86_64-Arch-Linux
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QQ1D.200105.002
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common device/xiaomi/sdm660-common vendor/xiaomi/twolip
============================================
[100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:115:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:125:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:135:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:145:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:155:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:166:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:177:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:188:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:199:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:210:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:221:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
error: vendor/xiaomi/sdm660-common/Android.bp:232:1: unrecognized module type "android_app_import"
11:47:08 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (59 seconds) ####
```

Comment: Your question is not exactly about failing code and might be better suited for https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android_app_import` is not a type that is known to the Android build tooling. It is a custom extension from the [LineageOS project](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_build_soong).

Comment: This answer seems not to be up-to-date anymore 
see https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/7937365/linux/latest/view/soong_build.html